# Getting DataPicker value MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public DateTime TheDate
    {
        get { return _TheDate; }
        set
        {

                _TheDate= value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("TheDate");

        }
```

XAML:

```
<DatePicker  Text="{Binding TheDate}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Put Date here"/>
```

I got `01/01/0001` as a default value. If I try to change it from the DatePicker, everything changes except the year (remains 0001). If I try to retrieve that value, I will stil get `01/01/0001` even though the DatePicker shows the day and month changed to something else.

Comment: Bind the `DatePicker` to the `SelectedDate` instead of the `Text` attribute

Comment: That did the trick apparently (to retrieve the value), but how can I make the date so It's not 01/01/0001 by default?

Comment: did you try to set _TheDate = DateTime.Now; (For first defining) in your ViewModel?

Comment: I tried an example

Difference
http://prntscr.com/jddpnh
http://prntscr.com/jddqe3
ViewModel
http://prntscr.com/jddqmc
XAML
http://prntscr.com/jddr4i

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use a `dependency property`. This makes binding a property to your `DateTimePicker` very easy.

```
public DateTime SelectedDateTime
{
    get { return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDateTimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedDateTimeProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedDateTime. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateTimeProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDateTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(YourModel), new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));
```

Now if you look at the parameters of `DependencyProperty.Register()` you can see, that there is a parameter called `PropertyMetadata` (the 3rd). This is your default value. In my case its `DateTime.Now`.

You can then bind your dependency property to your `DateTimePicker` like every other property

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDateTime}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Source properties don't be need to defined as dependency properties. And there is certainly no "you should use a dependency property" when defining a source property.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `SelectedValue` property of your `DatePicker` to your source property:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding TheDate}" ... />
```

...and set the value of the `_TheDate` field in your view model to the default date that you want to display:

```
private DateTime _TheDate = new DateTime(2018, 05, 05); //<-- default date
public DateTime TheDate
{
    get { return _TheDate; }
    set
    {
        _TheDate = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("TheDate");
    }
}
```